# Linking external documents to ADO Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, document, wiki

I am planning to use Azure DevOps for agile project management. I was trying out Jira / Confluence earlier. I do understand confluence is good for document management etc. In Azure DevOps, I understand there is Wiki for content management. I want to link all of my requirements, technical and other documentation currently existing as MS Word documents into ADO Wiki. I am unable to do that though - ADO Wiki allows a link of an object within ADO, but how do I get my word and other docs into ADO in the first place, and where do I put them - is there a general repository? Thanks

I am trying to find out how to link my external documents to ADO Wiki.

Comment: Hi, does my instruction help on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use markdown syntax to link external documents to ADO Wiki: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#links

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to presuppose the documents are hosted on another HTTP/Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your documents are not already hosted by another HTTP/Web Server. If they are then RoyWang-MSFT has your answer.

By Azure DevOps Wiki (ADO Wiki) convention each "project Wiki" is backed by a hosting git repository. Within each repository is a `.attachments` folder where "Insert File" (uploads/attachments) are housed. You may clone your project Wiki's repository and copy your files into this `.attachments` folder. Then you can use standard git commands to add, commit, and push your files. Then link to them like this `[YourDocDisplayname](/.attachments/YourDoc.docx)`.